# Play button onclick video player in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

call API using `fetch` and get response in console and assign values to table header.
after that creating one button in react js. Each button have one video URL which is got from API response

API response:

```
Camera_Number:"Camera_1"
Group_Name: "Group_1"
Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/0"

Camera_Number:"Camera_2"
Group_Name: "Group_2"
Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/1"
```

I stored this response in `useState` and pass this usestate response to video player source

```
  const actionButton = (params) => {
    setVideoName(params.videoName); // I am assuming but need to update videoName here
    setOpen(true);
  };
      headerName: "Actions",
          field: "Video_Name",
          cellRendererFramework: (params) => (
            <div>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                onClick={() => actionButton(params)}
              >
                Play
              </Button>
            </div>
```

Above code shows assign video_name to `Actions` header then I created one button. when I click one button, all of the videos open in one window and play all videos. But  I want it so that only that certain video that was clicked would show.

```
 <DialogContent>
            {response.map(({ Video_Name }) => (
              <iframe
                width="420"
                height="315"
                title="videos"
                src={Video_Name}
              />
            ))}
          </DialogContent>
```

How to resolve this issue using react-hooks.

for more details and code reference

> https://github.com/iamharry-dev/modal_popup

how to create index for video and pass videos to video player source. when i click that button certain video that was clicked would show.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response` state object contains the complete API response. `<DialogContent>` maps over this & create **multiple iframe** elements. We don't need to map & create multiple iframes -

```
<DialogContent>
  {response.map(({ Video_Name }) => (
...
```

Instead create dialog content based on name of the video where row was clicked.

```
const [videoName, setVideoName] = useState("");

function onCellClicked(params) {
    // maps to colId: "action" in columnDefs,
    if (params.column.colId === "action") {
      // set videoName for the row
      setVideoName(params.node.data.Video_Name);
      setOpen(true);
    }
}

// grid config
<AgGridReact
  ...
  rowData={response}
  onCellClicked={onCellClicked}>
</AgGridReact>

// access videoName in dialog content
<DialogContent>
 <div>{videoName}</div>
</DialogContent>
```

[image: Edit reverent-zhukovsky-gt4mln]

**Output** - Click on any row's play button. Result is that rows video url. You can now use this to play the actual video.

Comment: `setVideoName(params.videoName);` How to update video name here any idea or suggestion ??/

Comment: Please check `onCellClicked` in codesandbox.

Comment: @Harry You need to make a sandbox where I can run the problematic code & try to update it.

Comment: @Harry Please see updated answer with actual solution on codesandbox.